# Некорректный парсинг экранированного обратного слеша в JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, экранирование

Почему не работает парсинг `4n + 2` обратных слешей? Иначе говоря, как экранировать нечётное количество слешей?

```
// JavaScript

JSON.parse('{"content": "\\"}')
```

```
# Python 3

import json
print(json.loads('{"content": "\\"}'))
```

Онлайн-парсеры обрабатывают нормально (правда, некоторые обрабатывают не совсем так, как ожидается, выводя в результат удвоенное количество слешей).

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то JS тоже говорит `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потому что `\` экранирует второй `\` и в функцию попадает строка `'{"content": "\"}'`, где оно воспринимается как попытка экранировать кавычку.

Используйте 4 слеша, или 'row string'

```
import json

obj = json.loads('{"content": "\\\\"}')

print( obj ) # {'content': '\\'}
print( len( obj['content'] ) ) # 1 (это один экранированный слэш, а не два символа)

print( json.loads(r'{"content": "\\"}') )
```